# Adding Data to an Exception in Python

Tags: python, exception

I'm trying to create an exception that contains the typical string and an additional piece of data:

```
class MyException(RuntimeError):
    def __init__(self,numb):
        self.numb = numb

try:
    raise MyException("My bad", 3)
except MyException as me:
    print(me)
```

When I run the above I get the obvious complaint that I've got only two arguments in `__init__` but I passed three.  I don't know how to get the typical string into my exception and add data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass the first arg (`arg1`) into the parent exception's constructor and then do what you want with the second argument.

```
class MyException(RuntimeError):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        super().__init__(arg1)
        print("Second argument is " + arg2)
```

Note - if using Python 2, the call to `super()` is replaced by `super(MyException, self)`

Comment: He shows exactly what he wants to do with the second argument: save it for later use. (In the example, it would be available as `me.numb`.)

Answer (score 8):

The updated code based on the answer above looks like this:

```
class MyException(RuntimeError):
    def __init__(self,message,numb):
        super().__init__(message)
        self.numb = numb

try:
    raise MyException("My bad", 3)
except MyException as me:
    print(me)
    print(me.numb)
```

It outputs

```
    My bad
    3
```

Comment: You actually might put this under your original question below a separator like:

--------- UPDATE ---------

PS - glad it works, I didn't actually test it and figured it had a typo

Comment: @AdamHughes I wondered about that, but it seemed to me that it would confuse people to see an answer under the question. I imagined they would stop reading.